# Any fancy application of convergence (in probability, law, CLT, etc)?

Tags: inference, references, convergence, teaching

As part of the inference course in an applied stats masters degree, we've to prepare a talk about convergence (see, for example, Lehmann 1999 Chapter 2). We'll be explaining to other students some concepts and we'll show examples of different kind of convergences by the use of simulation.

It'd be nice to end the talk with an applied case from other fields of knowledge involving convergence. I'm thinking about some interesting application that will attract the attention of the class, something about astronomy for example?

pd. it's hard to pick the right tag for this question, if you happen to find a good one, please comment on it.